# "Cannot import url", "File outside of allowed directories" using --standard-json

Tags: solc, import, solcjs

I'm trying to understand how to use solidity's [JSON input-output API](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#compiler-input-and-output-json-description). Here's my json file;

```
{
  "language": "Solidity",
  "sources": {
    "StandardToken.sol": {
      "urls": [
        "file:///home/myuser/myproject/contracts/vendor/StandardToken.sol"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My best guess as to the "correct" command is;

```
cat input.json | solc --allow-paths /home/myuser/myproject/contracts --standard-json
```

I've tried lots of different relative paths, ending with or without a trailing slash, running the command in different directories, etc. But no matter what combination I try, I get back a json object with this error message;

> "Cannot import url
>   (\"file:///home/myuser/myproject/contracts/vendor/StandardToken.sol\"):
>   File import callback not supported"

I was getting this on `solc` version 0.4.24, but I upgraded to `0.5.1+commit.c8a2cb62.Linux.g++` and get the same issue.

Strangely, I get a similar message with `solcjs`;

```
$ cat input.json | solcjs --standard-json
Cannot import url (\"file:///home/myuser/myproject/contracts/vendor/StandardToken.sol\"): File import callback not supported
```

There seem to be a lot of github issues mentioning these error messages, but I can't make use of any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I change `input.json` to the following, without "file://" and with back-slashes instead of forward-slashes, solc is able to import the URL.

```
{
  "language": "Solidity",
  "sources": {
    "StandardToken.sol": {
      "urls": [
        "\home\myuser\myproject\contracts\vendor\StandardToken.sol"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the question first code bloc it seems that the path is not backslash formated

Comment: That works!

I don't think it's a thing about Window vs Ubuntu, though. My understanding is that the `file://` prefix is there to distinguish it from the other options, like `bzzr://` and `ipfs://` that are in the [example documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/using-the-compiler.html#input-description). So the fact that it doesn't work makes me think there's either a bug or the documentation is out of date.

Do you mind updating your answer to make the "removed the `file://` prefix" more prominent?

Comment: ...it also doesn't fix it for `solcjs`, which was my original use case. :/

Comment: I edited the answer as requested.